# Получение ошибки

Tags: php, html, парсер

Какую конструкцию мне необходимо реализовать, если я вызываю

```
file_get_contents($target)
```

где **target** - url страницы, а сервер присылает ошибку 404. Мне при условии появления ошибки 404 по этому адресу необходимо выполнить

```
file_get_contents($target)
```

для другого адреса через if/else.

Comment: юзайте get_headers (только это будет отдельный запрос, хоть кроме хедеров ничего получать не будет) либо уж таки curl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Официальная документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php) говорит, что функция `file_get_contents`

> Функция возвращает прочтенные данные или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки.

Код ошибки можно узнать проанализировав массив `$http_response_header` после вызова функции. Этот массив содержит все заголовки, пришедшие от сервера

Таким образом код у Вас должен быть таким

```
function getResponseCode($headers) {
  .....
}

$content = file_get_contents($target1);
if (
  $content === false &&  // === вместо ==, чтобы отличить '' от false
  getResponseCode($http_response_header) === 404
)
  $content = file_get_contents($target2);
```

Comment: `$http_response_header` с вами не согласен. Формально, конечно не функция возвращает, но заголовки доступны

Comment: @teran Не знал. Спасибо за уточнение

Answer (score 2):

> Функция *get_headers()* возвращает массив, в первом элементе которого содержится код ответа сервера. Я написал пример получения этого кода и последующих действий, в зависимости от полученного кода:

```
// Первая ссылка
$target = 'http://www.example.com';
// Если ошибка, перезаписать ссылку в $target
get_status($target) ?: $target = 'http://вторая ссылка';
// Получить контент
$content = file_get_contents($target);
var_dump($content);


function get_status($url) {
    preg_match('~\d{3}~', get_headers($url)[0], $http);
    return ($http[0] < 400);
}
```